# Load more user movies via AJAX in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, coffeescript

I have a search movies application (Rails 4) and in 'my_movies' page I'm trying to show 2 user movies on page load and then after clicking a link 'Load More' other 2 ones.

Now I get 500 (Internal Server Error) with this code. I think I have problems in my controller. What I'm doing wrong?

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :movies, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**models/movie.rb**

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  after_action :verify_authorized

  def my_movies
    authorize :user, :my_movies?
    if params[:id]
      @user_movies = current_user.movies.where('id < ?', params[:id]).limit(2)
    else
      @user_movies = current_user.movies.limit(2)
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

**views/users/my_movies.html.slim**

```
.row
  .small-12.columns.block.movies_container
    = render 'users/user_movies'

.row
  .small-12.columns.block.load_more_container
    = image_tag 'spinner.svg', style: 'display: none;', class: 'loading_icon'
    = link_to 'Load More', my_movies_user_path, class: 'load_more'
```

**views/users/_user_movies.html.slim**

```
- @user_movies.each do |movie|
  h2.user_movie data-id='#{movie.id}'
    = link_to movie.title, movie_path(movie)
```

**views/users/_user_movies.js.slim**

```
| $('.movies_container').append('
= escape_javascript(render(partial: 'users/user_movies'))
| ');
```

**js/user.coffee**

```
# when the page is ready for manipulation
$(document).ready ->
# when the load more link is clicked
  $('a.load_more').click (e) ->
# prevent the default click action
    e.preventDefault()
    # hide load more link
    $('.load_more').hide()
    # show the loading icon
    $('.loading_icon').show()
    # get the last id and save it in a variable 'last-id'
    last_id = $('.user_movie').last().attr('data-id')
    # make an ajax call passing along our last users movie id
    $.ajax
      type: 'GET'
      url: $(this).attr('href')
      data: id: last_id
      dataType: 'script'
      success: ->
        # hide the loading icon
        $('.loading_icon').hide()
        # show our load more link
        $('.load_more').show()
        return
    return
  return
```

**Screenshot of the error:**

[image]

**UPD:** After restarting Rails AJAX works fine, but I get doubled movies (the same are shown), instead of getting 2 others from database.

The error starts from here (2) and maybe here (1), because I sent user id's and not his last movie id.

[image]

Here is the console logs when the XHR starts:

[image]

How it can be fixed?

**P.S.** You can find this app [here in GitHub](https://github.com/kirbrown/movies_sherlock_rails), feature branch 'Loading more'.

Comment: Could you paste the log?
Or you can install https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors
It will help you to debug your rails code.

Comment: I add screenshot to the main post below.

Comment: I ment rails logs, or just go directly to this link thet you're requesting and you'll see an actual error

Comment: Updated below. Thanks for watching!

Comment: You have to add some pagination here and send incremented page value not user id or movie id. Take a look at https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari
or https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate. Here is a video tutorial how to implement it - http://railscasts.com/episodes/174-pagination-with-ajax?view=asciicast

Comment: But I don't need pagination on my page...

Comment: But load more button basically means that you have one page of movies and you want to load next one. It would be much cleaner to use pagination here and simply load next page on load more button click. So you can increment page value and load next batch when user clicks again. Or may be I didn't understand you goal.

Comment: Please, see the post below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I try to deal with it by using **will_paginate** gem and infinite scrolling, but have troubles in Chrome & Firefox with scroll detecting (I use [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/114-endless-page-revised?view=comments) railscasts technic).
So I decided to try [new](https://www.topdan.com/ruby-on-rails/simple-infinite-scrolling.html) idea (using **kaminari** gem) and it works perfect (see the code below) with the exception of I want to load movies as a long list like in first example by scrolling or clicking 'load more' button, doesn't matter. Now I only have a button witch slides my movies through pages without using original pagination. Maybe anyone knows how to transform it to long list, like I initially want?

Thanks to [Dmitriy Nevzorov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5444431/dmitriy-nevzorov), he suggested the right way in comments to original post.

**Models are the same as in original post**

**controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  after_action :verify_authorized

  def my_movies
    authorize :user, :my_movies?
    @user_movies = current_user.movies.order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(5)
  end
end
```

**views/users/my_movies.html.slim**

```
  .row
    .small-12.columns.block.movies_container
       = render 'users/user_movies'

  - unless @user_movies.current_page == @user_movies.total_pages
    .row
       .small-12.columns.block
          p.view_more
            = link_to('View More', url_for(page: @user_movies.current_page + 1))
```

**views/users/my_movies.js.slim**

```
| $('.movies_container').append('#{j render(partial: 'users/user_movies')}');
- if @user_movies.current_page == @user_movies.total_pages
  | $('.view-more').remove();
- else
  | $('.view-more a').attr('href', '#{url_for(page: @user_movies.current_page + 1)}');
```

**views/users/_user_movies.html.slim**

```
- @user_movies.each do |movie|
  h2
    = link_to movie.title, movie_path(movie)
```

**js/my_movies.coffee**

```
$ ->
  content = $('.movies_container') # where to load new content
  viewMore = $('.view_more')       # tag containing the "View More" link

  isLoadingNextPage = false  # keep from loading two pages at once
  lastLoadAt = null          # when you loaded the last page
  minTimeBetweenPages = 5000 # milliseconds to wait between loading pages
  loadNextPageAt = 1000      # pixels above the bottom

  waitedLongEnoughBetweenPages = ->
    return lastLoadAt == null || new Date() - lastLoadAt > minTimeBetweenPages

  approachingBottomOfPage = ->
    return document.documentElement.clientHeight +
        $(document).scrollTop() < document.body.offsetHeight - loadNextPageAt

  nextPage = ->
    url = viewMore.find('a').attr('href')

    return if isLoadingNextPage || !url

    viewMore.addClass('loading')
    isLoadingNextPage = true
    lastLoadAt = new Date()

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      method: 'GET',
      dataType: 'script',
      success: ->
        viewMore.removeClass('loading')
        isLoadingNextPage = false
        lastLoadAt = new Date()
    })

  # watch the scrollbar
  $(window).scroll ->
    if approachingBottomOfPage() && waitedLongEnoughBetweenPages()
      nextPage()

  # failsafe in case the user gets to the bottom
  # without infinite scrolling taking affect.
  viewMore.find('a').click (e) ->
    nextPage()
    e.preventDefault()
```

**P.S.** Updated project located [here](https://github.com/kirbrown/movies_sherlock_rails) in GitHub.